# Unable to alter UIButton in EKEvent code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ekevent

I'm trying to create a button that when pressed creates a calendar event, and changes the title of said button to "Event Created" or perhaps creates an an AlertView to the same effect. This is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)AddToCal:(id)sender {
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) {
       //Code to handle not-granted
    }
    else {
            //Code to create event          
            [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err;
            [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Sub", PrevDest] ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [AddReminder  setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Subscribed!"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event Added!"
                                                            message:@""
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
          }
    }];
    //Where I tested different placement of the code
}
```

Now this creates the event all fine and dandy, but it doesn't create an AlertView or change the title as confirmation, and even more, it makes my app freeze and become unresponsive to touches...  until, that is, I press the home button, then reopen the app, at which point the title changes, and my AlertView pops up.

I've tried putting the title changing code at the marked location, which makes it work, but this of course is outside the if(!granted), and would therefore cause the button to change no matter what. And even putting the code there causes the same freezing phenomena.

I really have no clue whats up with this. Has anyone on here had the same problem?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to see if the alert view ever gets created.

Comment: I put three breaks at the change title, create alert, and show alert. The program stopped in all three places, and the alert was non nil, however, it still did not show, and the button did not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event Added!"
                                                        message:@""
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
});
```

Comment: I see. I'll assume you also need to be in the main thread to change a UIButton title? Once I added my setTitle: code to that, everything worked perfectly.